# Inserting data using checkbox - PDO

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I have checkbox, that who is checked. That's will be inserted in my `table:inclusion`.
I want to insert data, using checkbox with other textbox, but I don't have any idea for inserting data using checkbox, please help me out of this problem! Tyia!

```
Error: Invalid argument supplied for each()
```

Here's my code:

```
//script
 $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var roomname = $('#text_name').val();
  var id = [];  
   $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
    id[i] = $(this).val();
   });
  if(roomname != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:'POST',
    data:new FormData(this),
    // data: {inclusion_name:inclusion_name},
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data)
    {
     alert(data);
     $('#user_form')[0].reset();
     $('#userModal').modal('hide');
     dataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Both Fields are Required");
  }
 });
```

insert.php

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("
   INSERT INTO rooms (roomname) 
   VALUES (:text_name)
  ");
  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':text_name' => $_POST["text_name"]
   )
  );

foreach($_POST["id"] as $id)
 {
  $statement = $connection->prepare("
   INSERT INTO inclusion (inclusion) 
   VALUES (:id)
  ");

  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':id' => $_POST["id"]
   )
  );
 }
```

Comment: Checkboxes are boolean values, meaning they're true or false. You'll probably want to insert into a MySQL `TINYINT`. It might be worth including a little snippet of the code for the checkbox so that people can help you better :)

Comment: how can I create a snippet? @Will

Comment: Copy paste the HTML code from your checkbox and format it like you have the others :)

Answer (score 1):

When a checkbox isn't checked, it will not send a thing. it won't exist as far as php is concerned.

With checkboxes you will want to have a "backup" value by use of a hidden form filed with the same name as the checkbox.

```
<input type="hidden" name="something_checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="something_checkbox">
```

If the checkbox is checked a 1 will be sent.
If the checkbox is unchecked a 0 will be sent by the "default" value provided by the hidden form.